# Employee shift schedule

Tags: excel, schedule

We're moving a couple people up to a higher position and I've inherited the "opportunity" to create a new shifting schedule. There's a lot of caveats and rules/restrictions to follow. I am trying to find out if there is an easy way to schedule these shifts on a static rotation, so that the agents will know when/what their next shift is.

We have 7 people on the team, 5 seniors, 2 juniors. 1 of the seniors will be leaving soon too, and will be replaced by a junior. Shifts must consist of 2 people (day shift - 2 people, night shift - 2 people). Junior cannot work on a shift alone, or with another junior. They work 12 hour shifts, 24/7, 7am - 7pm (day shift), and 7pm - 7am (night shift), weekends as well. A night shift cannot be followed by a day shift right away, at least 2 days off must be in between the end of a night shift and start of the next shift. All employees must have at least 200 hours per month, but not more than 220.

I've devised a simple rotation, but I'd need to tinker with it to adhere to the restrictions and rules, which is very tedious, and was hoping there was a easier/faster way to do this.

Thanks in advance to whoever has any insight/experience with this sort of thing.

Patrick.

Comment: I think this is similar to "timetabling problem" which you can find lots of resources

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)